# Unable to append records to linked table in MS Access. Key Violations issue

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, append, linked-tables

I am pretty new with sql server and dealing with the linked table.

I tried to append new records to a linked table that is from SQL server in MS Access but then it popped out error saying that all the data hasn't been added because of key violation.

I checked on the data in SQL server, there are 2 primary keys assigned to that table. I am not so sure if this is the problem.

I have tried to localised the linked table and using the same append query, it works fine.

Then, I used the appended table earlier (which i would assume that the table format is the same) and tried to append them to the linked table. It pops out the same error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: '2 primary keys assigned to that table.' - that's not possible (but maybe you have misunderstood  the term),  I am not so sure if this is the problem - nope - you have attempted to insert data that already exists in the table for which the key(s) insist must be unique. Please add your table definitions, sample data your insert statement and the exact error message.

Comment: Composite key is possible.

Comment: o. i found the problem. one of it is actually a function key. i was attempting to append multi folder but then i notice that i have to do it in a certain table order for the function key to work. Anyway.. Thanks guys.